# Tried to read incoming SMS content but getting Error in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, sms

Hi friends i am trying to read incoming sms but getting warning like this . Invocation of questionable method: java.lang.String.(String) found in: mypackage.MyApp$ListeningThread.run()

Here is my code is

```
public class MyApp extends UiApplication {
//private ListeningThread listener;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyApp theApp = new MyApp();
    theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
}

public MyApp() {
    invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {             

        ListeningThread listener = new ListeningThread();
        listener.start();

        }
    });
    pushScreen(new MyScreen());
}

private static class ListeningThread extends Thread {
    private boolean _stop = false;
    private DatagramConnection _dc;

    public synchronized void stop() {
        _stop = true;
        try {
            _dc.close(); // Close the connection so the thread returns.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            _dc = (DatagramConnection) Connector.open("sms://");
            for (;;) {
                if (_stop) {
                    return;
                }
                Datagram d = _dc.newDatagram(_dc.getMaximumLength());
                _dc.receive(d);
                String address = new String(d.getAddress());
                String msg = new String(d.getData());
                if(msg.startsWith("START")){
                    Dialog.alert("hello");
                }
                System.out.println("Message received: " + msg);
                System.out.println("From: " + address);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please correct me where i am wrong.Is possible give me some code to read incoming sms content in blackberry.

Comment: @Lucifer I am not getting any error but not able to get the dialog. when i am receiving incoming sms. Is there anything wrong with my code.please help.

Comment: Hello friendzz... let me know where i am getting wrong.

Comment: [this](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_listen_for_SMS_messages.html?nodeid=1357551&vernum=0) might help you

Comment: @Lucifer I am using code from your given link only. but did not achieved my goal.

Comment: then start googling, it is bit hard to get help for BB

Answer (score 0):

A few points about your code:

- That `invokeAndWait` call to launch a thread makes no sense. It doesn't harm, but is kind of waste. Use that method only to perform UI related operations.
- You should try using "sms://:0" as param for `Connector.open`. According to [the docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html), a parameter with the form `{protocol}://[{host}]:[{port}]` will open the connection in client mode (which makes sense, since you are on the receiving part), whereas not including the host part will open it in server mode.
- Finally, if you can't get it working, you could use instead the third method specified in [this tutorial](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Different-ways-to-listen-for-SMS-messages/ta-p/445062), which you probably have already read.

Answer (score 0):

The error you quoted is complaining about the use of the String constructor that takes a string argument.  Since strings are immutable in Java-ME, this is just a waste.  You can use the argument string directly:

> Invocation of questionable method: java.lang.String.(String) found in: mypackage.MyApp$ListeningThread.run()

```
//String address = new String(d.getAddress());
String address = d.getAddress();
// getData() returns a byte[], so this is a different constructor
// However, this leaves the character encoding unspecified, so it
// will default to cp1252, which may not be what you want
String msg = new String(d.getData());
```